How to use multiple formulas on nested data
I am trying to run multiple different formulas on nested data. I was able to code most of what I need, but I am not very familiar with functions or dealing with nested data, so I don't know how to get the information out of the lists now that I have it.
#packages and data
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)
install.packages("AER")
library("AER")
data(Affairs, package="AER")

#creating response variable
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs >  0] <- 1
Affairs$ynaffair[Affairs$affairs == 0] <- 0

#factoring some of the variables
Affairs <- Affairs %>% 
  mutate_at(c("affairs", "religiousness", "occupation", "rating", "ynaffair"), as.factor)

#nesting by religious group
by_relig_group <- Affairs %>%
  group_by(religiousness) %>%
  nest()

#Create formulas
gender_formula <- as.formula("ynaffair ~ gender")
age_formula <- as.formula("ynaffair ~ age")
occupation_formula <- as.formula("ynaffair ~ occupation")
formula_list <- list(gender_formula,age_formula, occupation_formula)

# Designate the models and function
model <- function(df, formula_list, index) {
    list(glm(formula = formula_list[[index]] , family=binomial, data = Affairs))
}

#Apply to each data group and formula list by formula number 
df1 <- by_relig_group %>% 
  mutate(model1 = map(data, ~model(., formula_list, 1)), 
         model2 = map(data, ~model(., formula_list, 2))) 

And it looks like the code worked, but now I am not quite sure how to get it out of its current form.
At a smaller level, I was able to get all of this to run
#create nested data frame
by_relig_group <- Affairs %>%
  group_by(religiousness) %>%
  nest()

#create a function to run the linear models
model <- function(df){
  glm(ynaffair~gender + age + yearsmarried + children + religiousness + education + occupation + rating,
               family = binomial,
             data = Affairs)
}

#run the models
by_relig_group <- by_relig_group %>%
  mutate(model = map(data,model))


#unnest the models using the broom package 
by_relig_group_unnest <- by_relig_group %>%
  mutate(tidy = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>% ## I can't figure out how to apply these two lines of code above
  unnest(tidy)

The end goal is to get the frequency of each level(next problem to solve), estimate (which I'll exponentiate to get the OR), CI, and p-value and export to Excel. If you have any suggestions on how to get CI while I am running this code, I'd be grateful for the advice.

One of several approaches, using the iris dataset and a linear model for demonstration:

create a grid of all combinations of group (here: Species) and formulas:

combinations <- 
expand.grid(group = unique(iris$Species),
            formula = c(as.formula('Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length'),
                        as.formula('Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length')
                        )
            )

    ## > combinations 
    ##        group                                  formula
    ## 1     setosa               Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length
    ## 2 versicolor               Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length
    ## 3  virginica               Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length
    ## 4     setosa Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length
    ## 5 versicolor Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length
    ## 6  virginica Sepal.Width ~ Petal.Width + Petal.Length


Iterate this data frame rowwise, using group and formula to run a model and extract the model coefficients. Use list to store objects whose length is neither 1 nor nrow into a single "cell".
Finally, unnest_wider the coefficients into separate columns:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

combinations |> 
  rowwise() |> ## !
  mutate(model = list( ## `list` packs result into single cell
                    lm(data = iris |> filter(Species == group),
                       formula = formula
                      )
                    ),
         ## because model is stored in a single-item list, we
         ## need to extract the model with `[[1]]` to work on it,
         ## then `list`-pack the two-item result (coefficients) again
         coeffs = list(model[[1]])
                      
  ) |> 
  ## spread coefficients into separate columns:
  unnest_wider(coeffs)


    ##   group      formula   model  `(Intercept)` Sepal.Length Petal.Width Petal.Length
    ##   <fct>      <list>    <list>         <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>
    ## 1 setosa     <formula> <lm>          -0.569        0.799      NA          NA     
    ## 2 versicolor <formula> <lm>           0.872        0.320      NA          NA     
    ## 3 virginica  <formula> <lm>           1.45         0.232      NA          NA     
    ## 4 setosa     <formula> <lm>           2.89        NA           0.702       0.247 
    ## 5 versicolor <formula> <lm>           1.25        NA           0.929       0.0669
    ## 6 virginica  <formula> <lm>           1.06        NA           0.535       0.149 


